# What verb best describes the process of engaging in a debate or argument with someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a verb which means to engage in a debate or argument. For example, how would I fill in the blank in the following sentence?

> "That is just my idea and I have no intention to _________."

The person saying this doesn't have time to debate.

Thanks!

Comment: Formulating an argument describes the process of invention; in other words, casting about for a way to persuade a person(s) of your point of view regarding some issue. What you seem to be asking, however, is the PROCESS of actually debating someone. The answerers below seem to understand what you're asking, but I'll edit your posting just the same, to make your question clearer. Don

Comment: "I have no intention to **argue.**" -- Where's the problem?

Comment: @rheto *argue* covers everything.

Comment: @Kris: Frankly, I was at a loss as to why the OP asked "what is the verb for formulating an argument?" There's a big difference between formulating an argument (which denotes the thinking process leading up to an argument) and arguing. If I'm splitting hairs, so be it. It's in my nature to do so, I guess. Come to think of it, though, isn't exactness of expression part of the raison d'être of this site? Don

Comment: @rhetorician What you understood at the beginning was what I meant, anyway lets leave the questions and answers as it is now at least they are consistent :) Better example sentence would have been `I must take my time to _____ my thoughts so that I can convince them`.

Comment: @EralpB: In other words, you could fill in the blank, for example, with the word "compose"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Dispute***
>
> 1. to engage in argument or debate.
> 2. to argue vehemently; wrangle or quarrel.

i.e. *That is just my idea and I have no intention to dispute the matter.*

Answer (score 0):

I have no intention *of contending, quarreling...

You could also phrase it as "I do not intend to contend or quarrel over this point"

Answer (score 0):

This is just my idea, and I have no intention of ***stirring things***.

Comment: "stirring things up" ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The 'up' isn't essential, in fact I prefer it without. I never like closing prepositions. They seem to bring matters to an abrupt and juddering halt - a bit like applying the brakes suddenly and causing discomfort to your passengers. They also lack elegance which as an Italian you must surely understand.

Answer (score 0):

The verb is totally dependent on the audience - if an intellectual the word "deliberate" or "debate"comes to mind
If the audience is more rustic, the word "talk" or "argue" is more common